# Exclude one folder in htaccess protected directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a directory protected by htaccess. Here is the code I use now:

```
AuthName "Test Area"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/***/.htpasswd"
AuthType basic
```

This is working fine. However, I now have a directory inside of this folder that I would like to allow anyone to access, but am not sure how to do it.

I know that it is possible to just move the files outside of the protected directory, but to make a long story short the folder needs to stay inside the protected folder, but be accessible to all.

How can I restrict access to the folder, but allow access to the subfolder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/11/26/enable-file-or-directory-access-to-your-htaccess-password-protected-site/) you can accomplish this by using `SetEnvIf`. You match each of the folders and files you want to grand access to and define an environment variable 'allow' for them. Then you add a condition that allows access if this environment variable is present.

You need to add the following directives to your .htaccess.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/directory/)$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/file\.php)$"  allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Comment: @SherwinFlight I follow above code but still asking password, how to exclude directory for upload images

Comment: The paths on the URI don't need the parenthesis and should be anchored to the start (^) instead of the end ($). This can also be done without using an environment variable by using `require`.

Answer (score 51):

Just create an .htaccess file in the subdirectory with the content:

`Satisfy any`

Comment: That can work but what if there is no directory because of `mod_rewrite` stuff.

Comment: Put that in a <Location> block

Comment: Looks like some versions of Apache 2.4.x no longer support the `Satisfy` directive. I was able to get this to work on a NearlyFreeSpeech server using just `Require all granted`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's simpler.

Comment: This answer is very short and unclear. Can you please explain what the code means?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer does not seem to run well with new Apache Versions, since it stopped working as soon as Apache Updates were rolled out on some of my customers servers.

I recommend the following approach:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "NO PUBLIC ACCESS"
AuthUserFile /xxx/.htpasswd

SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "(path/to/directory/)$" ALLOW

<RequireAny>
  Require env ALLOW
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: Which versions of Apache ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but two of these answers use the pattern:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/directory/)$" allow`

to set an environment variable and then check to see if it exists. The part in the quotes is a regular expression. This statement is saying that any path that ENDS with "path/to/directory/" matches and should set the variable, such as "administrationpath/to/directory/", but not "path/to/directory/index.html". The "$" matches the end of the string.

A better match would be:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/directory/" allow`

This means the URI path must begin with "/path/to/directory/" (the caret matches the start of the string) but can have additional content after the trailing slash. Note that this requires the trailing slash. To make it optional you could add two rules:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/directory$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/directory/" allow
```

or, with more pattern matching:

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/directory(/.*)?$" allow`

The parenthesis and question mark make an optional group and ".*" means zero or more characters.

Personally, I'd either use `require all granted` [1](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) in the subfolder's .htaccess or:

`require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m|^/path/to/directory(/.*)?$|"` [2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) in the parent's.

Comment: the "require" answer is the best one, cause it's working on latest versions of apache either

Answer (score 0):

For Apache 2.4, create a `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
Require all granted
```

Place it in the subdirectory you want to allow access to.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one worked for you because i am using it for folder **public/images**

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/public/images/*#">
    AuthName "Provider-Main Protected"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /your_document_root_folder/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

URL http://example.com/public/images allow anyone to access. Other folders have protections.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create a **.htaccess** in the subdirectory.

Just create as many variables as you need with **SetEnvIf** directive, and be sure the file or path name you want to allw/deny is part of the URI regex you pass to **SetEnvIf**, exactly like @Sumurai8 said, but set the regex to fit your needs, for the URI should start/end/contain a set of characters............