# Allowing public access to a protected directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file that protects my website.

```
# -FrontPage-

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

AuthUserFile /home/some_folder/public_html/project/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/some_folder/public_html/project/_vti_pvt/service.grp
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
AuthName project
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
```

I have a folder sitting on the top level of the site, same level as this file that I wish to make publicly accessible. But cannot figure out how :( Everything I do, putting a new .htaccess file with allow all satisfy any, environment vars, etc has no effect (Except breaking the site).

Can anyone help me make this folder and its contents accessible please?

Comment: Sidenote unrelated to your problem: there's also a [`LimitExcept` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#limitexcept) in case you're worried about not having enumerated all possible methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude one folder in htaccess protected directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697706/exclude-one-folder-in-htaccess-protected-directory)