# protect sub directories with a single .htaccess file but use different group for each subdir

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Since there is no [Directory directive](https://serverfault.com/questions/311197/htacces-sub-directories/) in .htaccess files like in the apache config file I wanted to ask if there is a solution of using a different authentication group on a sub dir basis?

I found out that is possible to exclude a sub dir with htaccess using Env variables. See: [Exclude one folder in htaccess protected directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697706/exclude-one-folder-in-htaccess-protected-directory)

I also know I could put a .htaccess in each sub dir which would overwrite the parent one. However I found no solution to make different settings for subdirs in a single .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [IF](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) which is supported since Apache2.4 in combination with Request_URI like so:

```
<If "%{Request_URI} =~ /subdir1/">
```